# Why must heat supplied in the definition of entropy be reversible? Can't it be irreversible after all it is a state function?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

The definition of entropy contains the term $Q_\text{rev}$ which means the heat supplied or taken out **reversibly**. I thought yes it can be after all only the initial & final states are important as entropy is a state function irrespective of the *process* heat is transferred. However I was baffled when I first read [Clausius' theorem](https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/understanding-entropy-2nd-law-thermodynamics/) where it is written that $dS \geq \dfrac{Q}{T}$. If $Q$ is transferred **irreversibly**, then $dS$ is greater than $\dfrac{Q_\text{irrev}}{T}$; if the heat transfer is **reversible**, then only $dS$ equals $\dfrac{Q_\text{rev}}{T}$. So, does that mean entropy depends on the process heat energy is transferred?? Then, how can it be a state function? Where am I mistaking? Please explain.

Comment: since $dS = \frac {\delta Q_{rev}}{T}$ you also have $TdS=\delta Q_{rev}$. As $\Delta S = S-S_0$ for fixed $S_0$ is a state function, $\Delta Q_{rev}$ also behaves like a state function (note the difference between $\delta$ and $\Delta$)

Comment: @user31748: You are proving it circularly!

Comment: I am not proving anything, I am trying to explain by illustrating it from a different angle.

Comment: @user31748: Ok, if entropy is a state function, doesn't that mean how I do the process reversibly or irreversibly, entropy must be same. So, why reversible? Can you tell?

Comment: it does not matter for the entropy how you got there, be it reversible or irreversible, but if you got there reversibly then usually it is easier to calculate the entropy change from the reversibly supplied heat transfer $\delta Q_{rev}$ via the equation $S_1-S_0 =\int_0^1 \frac {\delta Q_{rev}}{T}$

Comment: @user31748: It was the same thinking of me until I read Clausius Theorem:(The site which I've linked writes:  to determine the change in entropy between two equilibrium states, one must first “dream up” a reversible path between the two states and then evaluate the integral over that path. **Any other process path will give a value for the integral lower than the entropy change**.

Comment: @user31748: What does the bold line mean? Isn't it contradictory to the fact that entropy is a state function as in any other process connecting the same initial & final states, $\dfrac{\delta Q}{T}$ becomes different than entropy change?

Comment: It means that if the process is irreversible then $dS > \frac{\delta Q}{T}$ and also $S_1-S_0 > \int_0^1 \frac{\delta Q}{T}$, and then you cannot calculate $S_1-S_0 $ from the right side.

Comment: @user31748: This is my confusion, sir. First you tell "it does not matter for the entropy how you got there, be it reversible or irreversible" & then you said when irreversible process takes place, the entropy is different from $\dfrac{\delta S}{T}$. So, isn't it a discrepancy? I know I am in a great trouble having this confusion & also you & even any other experts are telling right but really can't getting me out of the discrepancy & confusion:(

Comment: $\Delta S = \int_0^1 {\frac {\delta Q_{rev}}{T}} > \int _0^1 {\frac {\delta Q_{irrev}}{T}}$ The first integral is useful to calculate the $\Delta S $, the second is not.

Comment: @user31748: So, be it irreversible process between two states, the entropy change is $\dfrac{\delta Q_\text{rev}}{T}$. And that's why we have the difficulty to find the entropy change from an irreversible process since it contains inequality, right? Hope, I'm right now?

Comment: That is right, now you have got it.

Comment: @user31748: But can you tell, sir what is actually going on during irreversible process that makes $\delta S > \dfrac{\delta Q_\text{irrev}}{T}$ true? BTW, you ought write your valuable comments as answer as they have really helped me:)

Comment: Would this [question and answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/189996/calculation-of-entropy-change-in-irreversible-cycles-meaning-of-delta-q-t-in/190050#190050) be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an infinitesimal heat transfer $\delta Q$ the inequality of Clausius states that 
$$\Delta S = S_1-S_0 = \int_0^1 {\dfrac {\delta Q_\text{rev}}{T}} > \int_0^1 {\dfrac {\delta Q_\text{irrev}}{T}}$$

Here $\delta Q_\text{rev}$ and $\delta Q_\text{irrev}$ denote reversible and irreversible heat transfers, respectively. Thus if the process is reversible and we know what $\delta Q = \delta Q_\text{rev}$ is at each step then we can calculate the entropy change from the integral $\Delta S = \int_0^1 {\dfrac {\delta Q}{T}} $. But if the process is irreversible the integral $\int_0^1 {\dfrac {\delta Q}{T}}$ only gives a lower bound for the entropy change not the actual change.

The difference between the entropy change and the integral is the internally generated entropy by the process $$\Delta S - \int_0^1 {\dfrac {\delta Q}{T}} = \sigma_\text{irrev} $$ and is characteristic to it. For example, a resistor $R$ with a dc current $I$ through it and kept at constant temperature in steady state generates $\dot \sigma = \dfrac {I^2R}{T}$ entropy per unit time and sheds the same to its environment along with ${\dot q = I^2R}$ heat flux.

Comment: +1. Thanks for answering, sir. However, sir, Though, I have understood the mathematical relation that $\Delta S . \int_0^1 \dfrac{dQ_\text{irrev}}{T}$, can you tell me what actually goes on during the irreversible process that makes this inequation true?

Comment: "dissipation" in all its forms and manifestations (friction, stiction, resistance, etc.,). For example, the magnetic domain walls between the neighboring domains are sticky and when are moving relative to each other, then magnetic energy dissipates and heat evolves and if you were to keep it at a constant temperature then you will dump net heat and entropy in the environment over a "BH" cycle.

Comment: So, all due to these non-conservative forces, $$dS = \dfrac{dQ_\text{actual}}{T} + \dfrac{dW_\text{lost}}{T}$$, which ultimately implies that $$dS > \dfrac{dQ_\text{irrev}}{T} $$ as $$\dfrac{dW_\text{lost due to irreversibility}}{T}$$ is always positive & greater than zero for irreversible processes. Now, sir, can't we measure this additional entropy & add to the $\dfrac{dQ_\text{irrev}}{T}$ in order to get the total entropy change? Then we can also measure the entropy change due to irreversible process without going to any reversible path. ....

Comment: ....So, why is it always advised to find the entropy change by "_dreaming_" a reversible path between the initial & final states? After all, we can measure the entropy change even for irreversible path by adding the additional entropy due to the work lost, right?

Comment: you are on the right track but this is a huge subject that is very difficult to answer in a few lines. I suggest that you read two articles: "RC Tolman, PC Fine -On the irreversible production of entropy,  Reviews of Modern Physics, 1948" and "PW Bridgman - The thermodynamics of plastic deformation and generalized entropy; Reviews of Modern physics, 1950"

Comment: Where should I find them, sir? on Arxiv??

Comment: your local university library

Comment: Then I have to wait for one more year:( Nevertheless, you helped me conceive the concept & for that I am really thankful to you:)

Comment: Tolman & Fine http://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/4872759.pdf

Comment: Thanks, sir , for providing the link. I have, meanwhile, also read [this MIT page](http://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/thermodynamics/notes/node48.html). It was also helpful. Thanks, again:)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you start with a system in some state $P_1, V_1, T_1$ and you add some quantity of heat $\Delta Q$ to it so the system changes to a different state $P_2, V_2, T_2$. The final state will depend on how you added the heat $\Delta Q$. Adding the heat $\Delta Q$ in a reversible process will result in different values for $P_2, V_2, T_2$ compared with adding the same amount of heat $\Delta Q$ in an irreversible process.

Entropy is indeed a state function, so if you know $P_2, V_2, T_2$ you can calculate the entropy change. Since reversible and irreversible processes will result in different values for $P_2, V_2, T_2$ they will also result in different values for the entropy change.

Comment: @user36790: a good example is the [Joule expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_expansion). In this process $\Delta Q = 0$ but $\Delta S > 0$ i.e. $\Delta S > \Delta Q/T$.

Comment: See, sir, the Joule Expansion can be carried on isothermally(reversible) or by free expansion(irreversible) leading to the same final state. So, is it not contradictory to your answer that for different processes, final states are different & so the entropy is different?

Comment: @user36790: A Joule epansion is by definition a free expansion. In a Joule expansion the temperature doesn't change. If you did the same expansion adiabatically the expanding gas would have to do work on something, and as a result the internal energy decreases and the final temperature is lower. The two final states are different.

Comment: Sir, I really feel sorry for my behaviour & I apolozise for that. Yours was helpful but the other's was the one that cleared my confusion. Thanking you for posting the answer. Please forgive me if it was a bad behaviour:)